# grease pencil closed shape

Tags: animation, modifiers, grease-pencil

[image]

in grease pencil , i cannot truly connect two points together . non of the options do that , they just place points on each other or they place a new stroke between them,unconnected.

so when i use subdivide , it does not look good ( as shown in picture above ).

in general , i like the ability of grease pencil in changing shapes entirely each frame. my purpose is like this : using some clean (like svg) objects , and animate their pos-rot-scale , and also be able to change their picture/shape with one button . thank you.

Comment: Hello. I don't think Grease Pencil is meant to subdivide the same way meshes are. I would recommend using the smooth brush to get the desired effect. If you need more vertices use the W shortcut key then subdivide and the smooth tool should work a treat.

Comment: Control + J joins two points together, it works in version 2.91, probably version 2.83 also.